# How can I delete a badly-received question that has upvoted answers?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

Alright, so this applies to both Programmers Stackexchange and Stackoverflow. I was on the programmers site and posted a question - I had one of those days where you missed the most obvious answer even though you've been staring at it for hours. I quickly noticed this the next day but I cannot delete my question due to it having answers. I cannot edit it either because the general question is just entirely incorrect. However, I am getting a ton of down votes on the question and I'm losing reputation. It's basically having a boat that constantly leaks without anyway of repairing it. This is what I get where I attempt to delete it:

[image]

The reason I post on here is because it applies to Stackoverflow as well and also I don't have enough reputation anymore to post on the Programmers Meta.

Comment: I'd prepend a short explanation, why this question is not worth reading (though the answers may be). I guess, you won't get much downvotes then.

Answer (score 5):

You can flag for moderator attention and ask for the question to be deleted.

Given that the question has clean-looking, well upvoted answers, the request may be declined in this specific case, though, even though it's a super-duper-duplicate.

In that case, I'd chalk it up as a learning experience and move on. Your net loss from downvotes on that question is currently 14 points; two upvotes elsewhere will already more than make up for it.